# Call another query onComplete of one query in apollo client using react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-apollo, react-apollo-hooks

> I am getting invalid hook call for nested queries[image]

```
const fetchNotifications = useNotificationsQuery({
        variables: {
            skip: SKIP,
            take: TAKE,
        },
        async onCompleted(data){
            let ids:Array<string>=[]
            data?.notifications?.forEach((e)=>{
                ids.push(e?.id+"")
            })
            setIds(ids)
            readNotifications()
        }
    });

    const readNotifications =()=> usereadNotifications({
        variables: { notificationIds: ids},
            async onCompleted(data){
                console.log("res"+data)
            }
    })
```

and usereadNotifications comes from

```
export const readNotifications = gql` mutation readNotifications($notificationIds: [String]!) {
       readNotifications(notificationIds: $notificationIds) 
} `; 
export const usereadNotifications = (options?: QueryHookOptions) => ( 
     useMutation(readNotifications, options) 
);
```

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri i have added snapshot for code

Comment: Instead of the snapshot, please add it as a snippet

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri i already tried that, i don't know why but if i add whole code i am getting error please add more description. I have added code .

Comment: Where is usereadNotifications coming from?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri that is Mutation exported from another file.

export const readNotifications = gql`
 mutation readNotifications($notificationIds: [String]!) {
  readNotifications(notificationIds: $notificationIds)
 }
`;

export const usereadNotifications = (options?: QueryHookOptions) => (
 useMutation(readNotifications, options)
);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `usereadNotifications` uses a hook `useMutation`, you can't wrap it into a function and try to execute it conditionally as it breaks the rules of hooks

However useMutation returns you a function which allows you to call the function to trigger mutation

So use it like

```
const fetchNotifications = useNotificationsQuery({
    variables: {
        skip: SKIP,
        take: TAKE,
    },
    async onCompleted(data){
        let ids:Array<string>=[]
        data?.notifications?.forEach((e)=>{
            ids.push(e?.id+"")
        })
        setIds(ids)
        readNotifications()
    }
});

const [readNotifications] = usereadNotifications({
    variables: { notificationIds: ids},
        async onCompleted(data){
            console.log("res"+data)
        }
})
```

Comment: Not working. giving syntax error. Property 'data' does not exist on type 'MutationResult<any>'

Comment: I was missing a closing bracket. Updated it. Also if you are using typescript please make sure you have proper typings

Comment: I already closed that bracket previously. I am still getting error

Comment: You can remove the usage of data, you don't need it

Comment: Few modifications in your answer worked for me . Thanks